# How to interface with Docker Engine from C program?

Tags: c, linux, docker, software-design

I need to handle running/managing Docker containers from a daemon written in C. But, SDK provided by Docker is available for Go & Python only.

Currently, i'm handling this by calling docker commands using 'system' function provided by glibc. But this is just a workaround and isn't a clean solution as compared to using APIs.

Are there any opensource C bindings available for Docker SDK (or) are there any C library to format & send REST API requests/ receive & parse REST API responses  to/from Docker engine?

I'm also considering writing a helper program in Golang which will use Docker Go SDK and i'll communicate with this helper from my program over some IPC mechanism(pipes or message queues) to make an API call. In case there are no C bindings for an SDK written in a different programming language, what is the effective way to use the functionalities of APIs of that SDK?

I'm trying to come up with an effective way to start/stop a container, get list of running containers, get stats on a particular container etc. from a C program other than relying on docker command line utility in Linux.

Comment: How about the REST API ?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I updated the question regarding REST API and elaborated with more details. I did find this https://github.com/danielsuo/libdocker , but it doesn't seem to be actively maintained anymore.

Comment: This looks a lot like a "help me find a library' question.

Comment: @c0der Make sure if a daemon process in golang is really what you want to maintain over a C self contained process. If Docker API changes because you moved to newer version you will have to maintain both source codes.

Comment: Not to mention that setup will be harder and you will need to establish some protocol for communication between processes.

Comment: I would go for using libcurl for communication with docker daemon over REST API.